# R - Error in class(x) - plm - only within and random effects models

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I have run into some difficulties with the plm function in R.

I am trying to run different panel data models on the same dataset and it works with the "between","fd" and "pooling" models, but *not* with the "within" or "random" models. Not sure what I am doing it wrong. Below is my code and the error message that I get. Would be grateful for any help!!

```
pdata_1<-pdata.frame(mydata_1,index=c("Country","Year"))
fd<-plm(Y~Category+Eurozone+Poverty_Rate,data = pdata_1,model = "fd")
pooled<-plm(Y~Category+Eurozone+Poverty_Rate,data = pdata_1,model = "pooling")
```

Code above works, but when I try this:

```
within<-plm(Y~Category+Eurozone+Poverty_Rate,data = pdata_1,model = "within") 
random<-plm(Y~Category+Eurozone+Poverty_Rate,data = pdata_1,model = "random")
```

It stops working and I get this error:

> Error in class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "pseries") : 
>     invalid to set the class to matrix unless the dimension attribute is of length 2 (was 0)

I also tried specifying the index again. Like this for example:

```
within<-plm(Y~Category+Eurozone+Poverty_Rate,data = pdata_1,index=c("Country","Year"),model = "within")
```

But I get the same error message. I tried googling it, but I really cannot understand the explanation (if there is any). Could you pls help?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: I believe this won't be reproducable for anybody if you do not provide a self-contained example or make your data available somewhere.

Comment: You might want to look at this new question (and its proposed answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60804415/r-plm-error-within-and-random-effects-models-pooling-between-first-differ/60808489#60808489